# Difference between Series of DataFrame and a Panel in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Is a `pandas.Series` made up of multiple `pandas.DataFrame` is similar to a `pandas.Panel`? On first look, they both appear to be very similar data structure. When do you decide to use a series of dataframe, and when do you use a panel?

Answer (score 1):

A `Panel` will generally be more memory/computationally efficient - a `Series` of `DataFrames` isn't much different than a different than a `Series` of arbitrary python objects - plus the `Panel` api should make operations easier.

```
In [18]: dfs = {i:pd.DataFrame({'a':np.linspace(0,100, 10000), 
                                'b':np.linspace(0,100, 10000)}) 
                for i in range(1000)}

In [19]: s = pd.Series(dfs)

In [20]: pnl = pd.Panel(dfs)

In [21]: pnl.sum()
Out[21]: 
      0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8    \
a  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000   
b  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000   

      9     ...       990     991     992     993     994     995     996  \
a  500000   ...    500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000   
b  500000   ...    500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000  500000   

      997     998     999  
a  500000  500000  500000  
b  500000  500000  500000  

# equivalent with a series of frames
In [24]: s.apply(lambda x: x.sum()).T

In [22]: %timeit pnl.sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: x.sum()).T
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop
```

Note that `Panel` is somewhat less used than the rest of the `pandas` api - depending on what you're trying to accomplish you might have more luck with a `DataFrame` with a [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) or something more specialized for multi-dimensional data, like [`xray`](http://xray.readthedocs.org/en/stable/)